# How to rewrite the code in order to get rid of the duplicate codes in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm learning ios dev through making an app. I wirte code in Swift and for the backend, I use Firestore. This app is supposed to be the multiplayer tic tac toe.

Since two people access the same data, I store data in Firestore, but every time if I want to check inside of the data, I have to read the same document (which is ok).

In my Viewcontroller, I made several functions that all of them need to get the data from Firestore. So, everytime I have to fetch the same document with same code.

```
let docRef = db.collection(K.FStore.newGameCollection).document(gameDocumentID)
        docRef.addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                let gameDocData = documentSnapshot?.data()....
```

and some of the examples are

```
func changePlateImage (plate: UIButton) {
    
    let docRef = db.collection(K.FStore.newGameCollection).document(gameDocumentID)
    docRef.addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            let gameDocData = documentSnapshot?.data()
            let isPlayer1 = gameDocData?[K.FStore.isPlayer1Turn] as? Bool
            let fruitImage = isPlayer1! ? K.Image.apple : K.Image.pineapple
            
            plate.setImage(UIImage(named: fruitImage), for: .normal)
            
            self.changeGameBoard(index: plate.tag, fruit: fruitImage)
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
func changeGameBoard (index: Int, fruit: String){
    
    let docRef = db.collection(K.FStore.newGameCollection).document(gameDocumentID)
    docRef.addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            let gameDocData = documentSnapshot?.data()
            var gameBoard = gameDocData?[K.FStore.gameBoardField] as? Array<String>
            // add name of the fruit in the gameBoard
            gameBoard?[index] = fruit
        }
    }
}
```

As I said before, every time before I run the functions I write the same code. If I need to write the same code in every function, is there any better way to refactor this function? or I should just make a huge function? Sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to write a function to get data.. and then manipulate it according to condition

```
func getGameDataFromDB (completion: @escaping(_ gameDocData: gameDocDataTypeHere?, _ error:Error?)->Void ) {
    
    let docRef = db.collection(K.FStore.newGameCollection).document(gameDocumentID)
    docRef.addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            completion(nil,err)
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            completion(documentSnapshot?.data(),nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
 getGameDataFromDB { (data, error) in
                var gameBoard = data?[K.FStore.gameBoardField] as? Array<String>
            // add name of the fruit in the gameBoard
               gameBoard?[index] = fruit
            }
```